# Bar charts not getting displayed correctly when bar is below zero (chart.js)

Tags: chart.js

How to solve this issue that I am facing in a bar chart using chart.js?

Bar charts are not being displayed correctly when the bar is below zero in chart.js

```
datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'Data1',
                        borderColor: "#2874A6",
                        backgroundColor: "#2874A6",
                        pointBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        fill: false,
                        type: 'bar',
                       data: scheme_returns,
```

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is not clear, My suggestion is make use of `ticks`. It will help the chart to have `min` and `max` axis values. just add the below code in `yAxes` scale

```
ticks: {
           suggestedMax: 100,
           suggestedMin: -10
        }
```